# How to add footer to bottom of each page when converting HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, wkhtmltopdf

I am converting my HTML into a PDF report. I want the footer to show up at the bottom of the last page, even if there is a single line of text on that page. Can you please help?

I am using wkhtmltopdf tool to convert the files. I have searched a lot and only solution i could find is this:

```css
    body{
    position:releative;
    }
    
    footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    float:right;
    }
```

This generates a footer on the bottom of the first page.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

i recommend that you can use tcpdf. try this https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/